# React redux renders store state change, immediately then refresh app to initial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

had struggle for a while with this one, I followed all the instructions and checked a lot of times, this is the code:

```
const CREATE_BOOK = 'CREATE_BOOK';
const REMOVE_BOOK = 'REMOVE_BOOK';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  books: state,
});

const createBookAction = book => ({
  type: CREATE_BOOK,
  book,
});

const BookReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_BOOK:
      return [...state, action.book];
    case REMOVE_BOOK: {
      const index = state.findIndex(action.book);
      return state.slice(0, index).concat(state.slice(index + 1, state.length));
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books: BookReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const initialState = {
  title: '',
  category: 'Action',
  id: () => (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(),
}

class BooksForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const { target: { value }, target: { name } } = event;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    this.props.createBookAction(this.state);
    //this.setState(initialState);
  }

  render(){
    const categories = ['Action', 'Biography', 'History', 'Horror', 'Kids', 'Learning', 'Sci-Fi'];
    const categoriesBox = categories.map(cg => <option key={cg}>{cg}</option>);
    return (
      <form>
        <input name="title" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" />
        <select name="category" onChange={this.handleChange}>{categoriesBox}</select>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
};

const App = props => {
  const { books: { books }, createBookAction } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <BooksForm books={books} createBookAction={createBookAction} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, { createBookAction })(App);

const AppWrapper = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Container />
  </Provider>
);
```

The thing is, there is a render below all this and it's supposed to render a list ( which is also present but not included here ) with the new submitted book. It does for like a second and then it re-renders to it's initial state again ( no books ). I wonder if it's a state change but checked all the sources and still can't find what I'm missing. Also, the combined reducer is on purpose.

**UPDATE**
checked with redux-logger, and what it's doing is basically, when the button it's pressed, it updates the state but then it refreshes the page ( and re-start the app ) , showing it like in it's beginning state.

Comment: you should try add module redux-log to see what happen in store and figure out solution. Seem like BookForm doesn't use any props value so it is not re-render when store change

Comment: preventDefault ?

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    books: state.books
  }
};`  ... prepare [example]

Comment: @ThanhTuấn checked the logger, and what it's doing is basically, when the button it's pressed, it updates the state but then it refreshes the page ( and re-start the app ) , showing it like in it's beginning state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved it. The issue was that the submit button had a `type="submit"`. Changed to `type="button"` and all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `<button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit">Submit</button>`

into `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`

Comment: It's same, onSubmit help catch all value in form and submit ( raw html ).

Comment: Inside the `handleSubmit`, he can call the `preventDefault` method of `event`